# Armazenar e recuperar variável contendo lista HTML usando localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, localstorage

Tenho um projeto e estou usando `localStorage` como banco de dados. Uso isso pra salvar uma lista que o usuário pode editar e adicionar assim:

`localStorage.setItem(local, $("#lista").html());`

No html fica assim:

```html
<ul data-role="listview" contenteditable="true"  id="lista">
   <li></li>      
</ul>
```

Minha necessidade é recuperar cada informação entre cada `li` em variáveis ou ate mesmo um *array*.

Quando salva, o navegador enfia html dele mesmo... e bota classe lá li. 
ai to usando:

```
var teste = lista.split(/<li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c">|<\/li>|¤/);
```

Pra retornar cada valor dentro de cada li.

Só que ao recuperar usando `teste[1]`, `teste[2]`... funciona pela metade.

Por exemplo: Valor salvo por inteiro antes do processo de *split*:

> ,teste1,,teste2,,teste3,,teste4,

Aí eu uso `teste[1]` ou `teste[3]` ele retorna corretamente. Quando uso `teste[2]` ele não retorna nada.

Se alguém tiver alguma solução. `replaceAll` não é compatível com meu projeto.

#### PÁGINA QUE RECEBE O VALOR:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="teste.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onClick="att()">Mostrar</button>
    <div id="boxgeral">BOX GERAL</div>
</body>

</html>
```

#### PÁGINA QUE SALVA O VALOR:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="teste.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="titulo2" id="titulo2" value="" placeholder="Titulo" />
     <h5> Opções:  </h5> 
    <ul data-role="listview" contenteditable="true" id="lista">
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <button id="salvar">Salvar</button>
    <button id="limpar">Deletar</button>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Código Javascript:

```
var pag = 'pag1';
var titulo = localStorage.getItem(pag);
var lista = localStorage.getItem(titulo);


$(function () {

    $("#salvar").click(function () {
        var local = document.getElementById('titulo2').value;
        localStorage.setItem(pag, local);
        localStorage.setItem(local, $("#lista").html());

    });


    if (localStorage.getItem(titulo)) {

        $("#lista").html(localStorage.getItem(titulo));
        document.getElementById('titulo2').value = titulo;

    }

    $("#limpar").click(function () {
        localStorage.removeItem(titulo);
        localStorage.removeItem(lista);

        alert(localStorage.getItem(titulo));
        alert(localStorage.getItem(lista));

        window.location = window.location;
    });
});



function att() {

    var teste = lista.split(/<li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c">|<\/li>|¤/);

    alert(teste);
}
```

Comment: Poste um trecho de código qu dê ara reproduzir ai, senão teremos que escrever um HTML, função e etc só para poder te ajudar...Se puder poste todo seu HTML ai ou algo que possamos copiar e reproduzir sem muito trabalho.

Comment: Oi paulo, sou novo aqui e fico perdido nessa onda de formatação.
tive que upar uma pagina demo aqui e botei os links..
pq ao por o codigo tava formatando pela metade..
enfim, dê uma olhada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro gravares no `localStorage` com um objeto que represente o HTML em vez de gravar o HTML todo. Podes fazer algo assim:

```
var conteudo = $("ul#lista > li").map(function(){
    return {
       classes: this.className,
       html: this.innerHTML
    } 
}).get();
```

e depois usas:

```
localStorage.setItem(local, JSON.stringify(conteudo));
```

Para recuperar podes usar:

```
var json = localStorage.getItem(titulo);
var lis = $(JSON.parse(json)).map(function(){
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.className = this.className;
    li.innerHTML = this.html
    return li;
});
$("#lista").append(lis);
```

Desta maneira tens os elementos `li` separados em objetos e é mais fácil de lidar com eles.

Nota:

Não percebi bem a lógica que queres usar com o `titulo` mas se cada `li` tiver o seu próprio titulo podes juntar isso ao objeto em cima.

Comment: Perfeito, era o que eu queria.
Tive que adiconar $( ".li" ).remove();  ao recuperar o codigo, pos, ele recuperava junto com o que era presente no html. ai salvava sempre um li em branco.

* a logica amigo, é que ele recebe um id por outra pagina, podendo assim, ter varios bancos de dados,  so mudar o id, e me permite salvar uma pagina zerada... so por a id ja salva, ele recupera o li daquele id.
é pq resumi o codigo.
grato.

Comment: @FelipeLeão ótimo que ajudou. Se quiseres podes também usar assim: `$("#lista").empty().append(lis);`

Comment: @FelipeLeão fiz uma alteração, reparei que a string estava com conteúdo do jQuery desnecessário. Testa juntar isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/90597/revisions

Comment: Isso mesmo sergio, ja testei a aplicação e funcionou,
fiquei usando alert pra verificar o que tava sendo salvo kkk rs.
thanks.

Comment: @FelipeLeão ótimo! Tinha esquecido esse detalhe que converte para uma array nativa.